# How to get selected custom option value in checkout onepage in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to show the selected custom option in checkout onepage.  I'm trying this, but it's not working:

```
<?php
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$items = $cart->getAllItems();
?>

<?php foreach($items as $item): ?>

    <?php foreach($item->getProduct()->getOptions() as $o): ?>
        <?php foreach ($o->getValues() as $value): ?>
            <?php echo $value['title'] ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This returns all custom options that I created. How to return only selected one by the customer?

Comment: I would guess that $value has a selected attribute or something similar? you'd have an if inside your foreach loop (the third one) and check there.

Comment: I have not found any option called selected or similar with var_dump or print_r in $value.

Comment: where is the value that the user selected stored? possible options: session, database, ui...

Comment: In database. More specifically in sales_flat_quote_item table.

Comment: is that returned from Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()?

Comment: Yes, it is. Like the code above.